# Tile over Luan which is glued to a cement floor

Tags: flooring, tile, installation

Can tile be laid over luan that is glued to a cement floor?  WE are updating a second kitchen and bath.  pulled up the origianl vinyl sheet lino.  Luan is in excellent condition and glued tightly to the cement floor.

Can we time right over this.  We think it may be a nightmare to scrape all of the luan and glue off of the cement floor.  Will the luan react to the tile mud over time even if we use a good product like superflex?  I keep getting mixed answers on which way to go w/this.

Comment: I would never make that sandwich. Ever. Chileab Construction answered correctly (the same as I would answer). I don't know how long that luan was there as You state that it's in 'excellent condition', but I do not trust this solution. Wood + concrete is ok temporary only and for uses like formwork for cast concrete and poured concrete. Then again - it's Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it: yes.  Will it come back to bite you:  probably yes.
Trapping wood between two cement building layers, in my opinion is asking for problems. 
If there is any moisture wicking through that cement slab it will be trapped beneath your tile in the wood - 
Do the work and scrape that floor.  I have spent days scraping a floor to prep for tile properly.  It is worth it knowing that I will not get a call back in 5 years.